# iPad's camera causing problems with my UIToolBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have the following code which launches the iPad's camera when the camera button on a UIToolBar is pressed.  But whenever the view is dismissed, the toolbar doubles in hieght.  I'm not sure why it is doing this.  It just suddenly gets stretched up in height.

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
pickerController.delegate = self;
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
pickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;

if (self.isProfileFlag)
{
    //test
}
else
{
    pickerController.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    pickerController.showsCameraControls = YES;
}
[self.topLevelParent presentModalViewController:pickerController animated: false];
```

And to dismiss it, I have: `picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];`

However, once I rotate the screen, the toolbar is back to normal until i open the camera again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon,

I can't say for sure based solely on the information that you have provided, but it seems like you bar is fixed when redrawn. So, and this is a dirt fix (you should try to figure out what is really happening) but you can try [jonsBar setNeedsDisplay] right after you dismiss the modal. This should redraw the toolbar.

One thing to look at is are you using a Nib for your layout or are you drawing your UI via code. I have seen some weird thing's when drawing everything with code, but your mileage may vary.

If you can provide more detail, I may be able to help further, but do take a look at the above first.